# 2007 Pontiac Grand Prix - Car overheating when AC is on

Tags: overheating, pontiac, grand-prix

Have replaced the radiator, thermostat, water pump, L hoses and replaced a transmission pan gasket. Car has passed a block test. Car has been with the mechanic for 4 days now...help??

Comment: Are the radiator fan working properly?